# LESS: Mixin and variable names by variable value

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, svg, less

I'm trying to do generating icons from svg-files easier.
(And also generate png-sprite fallback to support ie8).
Use grunt.js and less.

That's idea realized bu 2gis.ru:
http://www.slideshare.net/codefest/codefest-2014-2 (russian), but i have only this slides and name of technologies thay use: node.js, npm, grunt,js, less.

look it part of code, that show what i want:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvo6zkt0vxeuurw/codefest-2014-2-80-1024.jpg?dl=0]

Now i make this template: https://github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up (if you clone you need to use 'npm install')

One step not working.

1. Put svg-icons in *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/tree/master/assets/dev/img/svg-icons*
2. Put png-icons in *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/tree/master/assets/dev/img/png-icons*
3. Use grunt
4. All sprite created in *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/tree/master/assets/build/img*
5. .less files create in *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/tree/master/assets/dev/css/less/mixins/bg-icon/temp* It maked by spritesmith and I can't change anything in it

Now about less files.

1. *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/blob/master/assets/dev/css/less/mixins/bg-icon/temp/datauri.less* contain base64 code for svg icons. Class names based on file names, i can only set suffix and prefix
2. Files like *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/blob/master/assets/dev/css/less/mixins/bg-icon/temp/sprite.datauri.less* contain mixins and variables to create sprite css (for png icons). I create sprite for svg icons for take from it less width and height (datauri task give only base64).
3. **Problem in *github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/blob/master/assets/dev/css/less/mixins/bg-icon/bg-icon.less***. There is 2 mixins - for svg and png icons. I need use that with parametr "filename" to create css for icons, but i dont know how! I put there comments.

P.S. I removed url becouse need more reputation to post it.
P.P.S. I'm very sorry for my english :(

Comment: It's all can be implemented with a 2-3 line mixin. The only question is: "LESS code that i receive:" - where do you receive it from? Is it some external tool or what? Can you modify it? Also by `.bg-icon(@filename);` do you actually mean filename or just icon name, i.e. do you need a possibility to generate classes for each icon separately or it's just better to generate all of them at once.

Comment: Though to be honest, there're already enough sprite-generation answers/examples here at SO and this one most likely overlaps with one of those in 96.3%.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it's even more hard to answer it after your edit. Note that SO is for asking specific questions about specific peaces of code not just I have a file somewhere can you fix it for me.

Comment: Either here're few tips to improve your. 1. Get rid of inline JavaScript hacks: Less has got its [`extract`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) function 1.5 years ago. 2. Do not create variables and mixins for every single image property and for every single CSS property. Note that all images of the same sprite share all of their properties except position (and optionally size). Same way all sprite styles share all properties except file, position (and size). Use that - keep your code DRY. 3. Having 6 files with ~60 lines each only for a single icon is an absolute overkill.

Comment: But all this is offtopic here. So getting back to the problem - you need to post code here and ask a specific question (e.g. "Here's the  code, I want it do this and that, I tried to do it like this or that but it failed... etc.").

Comment: 6 files - for all icons in all dpi variant with fallback to ie8... And all of this files generated by grunt tasks, not by me. All problem code - there github.com/andrey-hohlov/template-mark-up/blob/master/assets/dev/css/less/mixins/bg-icon/bg-icon.less, i post another code for answer on u questions.

Comment: And my question - how can i use mixin name and variable names by another variable value, just it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then.

> how can i use mixin name and variable names by another variable value

So:

(1). To refer to a variable by its name stored in another variable use ["Variable Referencing"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names) syntax, e.g.:

```
#example {
    @banana: 22px;
    @potato: "banana";

    width: @@potato; // -> 22px
}
```

(2). You can't call a mixin by name set in a variable, so to selectively invoke a mixin depending on a variable value use ["Pattern Matching"](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching), e.g.

```
.mixin("banana", @values...) {
    color: @values;
}

.mixin("potato", @values...) {
    background-color: @values;
}

#usage {
    .mixin("banana", tomato); // -> color: #ff6347
    .mixin("potato", wheat);  // -> background-color: #f5deb3
}
```

If you can't modify those mixins - generate wrappers:

```
.mixin(peach) {.mixin-peach()}

#usage {
    @variable: peach;
    .mixin(@variable); // invokes .mixin-peach
}
```

Comment: You are great and very patient! WE does it! I'm happy =)